# Redirect Callback URL after processing

Tags: php, callback

I am using an API; and I use a callback url for monitoring certain parameters sent by the API and storing them in a mysql database; which is **working perfectly fine**.

After storing the data in DB I want to **redirect the page to another page** for some other processing.

The relevant code **after DB insert** is as follows:

```
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
if($count == 0){
$conn = null;
exit;
}
else{
$conn = null;
header("Location: https://www.example.com/message_usage?id=$id");
exit;   
}
```

If i call the url directly as:

```
https://www.example.com/message_usage?id=1234
```

it is working fine. But redirect seems not happening in original code. Can't we redirect a callback url after processing in php? If so, how to do it ??

Comment: Do you use ajax?

Comment: No Ajax. Plain php.

Comment: Whats the `var_dump` of `$count`?

Comment: As explained in the original post, the data is getting updated correctly in DB. Even without a success check and directly providing a redirect was not working.

Comment: In your provided code, your statement evaluates to `true`, otherwise it would redirect you, because the redirect syntax is correct. This means `count` is `0`. You checking if the return value of `rowCount` is a string, but `rowCount` returns an integer. Please show more of the code where you update and insert.

Comment: $stmt->execute(); 
$conn = null;
header("Location: https://www.example.com/message_usage?id=$id");
exit;

Comment: Even without success check, it is not redirecting as explained in my post above.

Comment: Where is your `id` coming from? Maybe its undefined.

Comment: How are you making the request to the PHP in the question? How are you determining that the redirect is not happening? If the redirect is not happening, what *is* happening instead?

Comment: @ T K Yes, you were correct. I checked using postman and the id was undefined. Did a foolish thing while checking for id on API update. I corrected it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Redirect still not happening ??

Comment: This callback processes a webhook call? What's the client that's calling your callback URL? Doing a redirect for such a call is not a very good idea.

Comment: I think the count is  0 therefore you are not redirected check the $count

Answer (score 2):

Most clients that call webhooks/API callbacks would ignore a redirect, and wont peform additional HTTP requests just because your endpoint thinks they should. They are calling back to inform you of something that happened in their end, and it's your system's responsability from that point onward.

Many would even consider any status code different from `200` a failure code, and store that response accordingy in their side.

Redirects are **not** the correct way to go for something like this. Whatever other processing you need to go should happen within the **original HTTP request**.

At best, it wont work, and only the first part of your process will be executed (as you discovered).

At worst, the API calling you back will use the status response as a failure, which might impact how your data is processed in their side.

Comment: @Pamela Great. Remember that you can accept the answer if you find it useful as well.